# What is the difference between "Static binary instrumentation" and "binary rewriting"

Tags: binary, instrumentation, rewriting

As far as I know, Static binary rewriting is:

*Static binary instrumentation occurs before the program is run, in a phase that **rewrites** object code or executable code.* (which is defined by [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-606.pdf))


So I thought the *Static binary instrumentation* is same with *binary rewriting*.


However, yesterday my professor said that "*Static binary instrumentation* is different with *binary rewriting*".

I tried to search several paper and article, but I still have no idea on why they are different. 


***Question:***

Are those two concepts different?
If there exists even any subtle difference, what is the difference between "Static binary instrumentation" and "binary rewriting"?

Comment: Did they say “is different with” or “is different to”?

Comment: @Holger Yes. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Never mind. I don’t want to criticize your English, in this specific case, you have to care, because there is a really different meaning, depending on which word your professor used. “*X is different with Y*” could mean “*X becomes better (or worse/easier/harder) when using Y for it*”, so it would not mean that these are entirely different things. In contrast, “*X is different to Y*” (or “*than Y*”) would indeed mean these are different things. So here, the wording is important.

Comment: As you said, those two concepts are not entirely different. More specifically, "the concept of *Binary rewriting* is subset of *Static binary instrumentation*" was what my professor described. However, every papers what I found on static binary instrumentation uses binary rewriting techniques. 
So I think those two concepts are same, it's hard for me to accept professor's opinion. ;(

Comment: So your question is “what would ‘static binary instrumentation’ be without ‘binary rewriting’?” Indeed a good question. Perhaps best to ask your professor. I can’t imagine much. Perhaps, replacing link libraries.